# некорректно вводит данные в БД MYSQL из C#

Tags: c#, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать ввод слов:"System.windows.Forms.Textbox,Text"? В этом загвоздка.Если нужно скину код запроса.

Comment: Может просто нужно получать значения полей ввода, вместо сериализации их самих?

Comment: У меня вот как данные поступают в бд(это часть запроса): comminsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comminsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family",textBox1);
            comminsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2);
            comminsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", textBox3);
            comminsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", textBox4);
            comminsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", textBox5);

Comment: Ну так, наверное, что-то вроде `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: Не пойму если честно) возможно неверная фраза "AddWithValue" и её заменить на "Insert"?

Answer (score 0):

После textBox нужно добавить ".text"